# Use different toolchain with configure on Linux

Tags: linux, gcc, arm, toolchain

I have a toolchain for my target system (arm) correctly installed at $TOOLCHAIN.

The output of `ls $TOOLCHAIN` is: `bin  debug-root  include  lib  lib32  lib64  sysroot`.

The content of bin/* is not prefixed, i.e gcc, g++, as, ...

Now, I have a source distribution of an application I'd like to compile with the given toolchain for this target system. The source distribution has a *configure* script.

How to do this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: The typical cross configure needs at least `./configure --host=arm-linux --build=x86-linux` or something like that.  Often there are many other programs and defines that may need to be set; You probably need to specify a package.  The package may need to compile programs on the build machine as well as for the ultimate target.

Answer (score 1):

Building a cross compiler/binutils is often very hard, and it doesn't allow you to test your programs.
Virtual machines are very slow and create a strong separation which make hard to share files between the host an the VM.

The easiest solution is [Qemu-User-static](https://wiki.debian.org/QemuUserEmulation) : system-calls and instructions are wrapped in user mode to the native kernel.

Download or extract a rootfs.

- Copy it to a sub-folder of you real root directory.
- Copy qemu-user-*(the name of your mips arch)*-static to the root of the target directory.
- Correctly bind mount everything.
- Copy /etc/resolv.conf to /your_path_to_target/etc/resolv.conf
- Chroot to it by executing /bin/bash.
- Use the rootfs as if you were using a real mips based machine.

Things became very simple : Many libraries aren't compiled because of things like hard-coded paths *(you'll face many; many problems like the one you have with cross-compiling, a typical case)*. Here all happen as if you build packages natively and you'll have to type`./configure`.